# Purpose of session('status') in Laravel 5.5 view file?

Tags: laravel-5.5

I'm new to Laravel, and after running php artisan make:auth, the associated home.blade.php file uses a call to check for and display session('status').

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

        <div class="card-body">
            @if (session('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
            @endif

            You are logged in!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Does this actually do anything? I've searched and drilled through many files and can't find out if this is actually used.

Comment: It is used for displaying messages after redirection.
It's used in forgot password module.
On reset password form, when you submit form with email, it gives you a success message saying,
Reset password mail sent to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside Laravel's core files ( inside vendor )

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords.php

it is used.

Look for the function,

```
protected function sendResetResponse($response)
```

It returns the status with success string.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: To be used for ex. with, in your controller, ```return redirect('home')->with("success", "Your message");```